# Button action throwing exception when i loaded it from Background to my Mainclass

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I am trying to load `UIView` from Background class to my Main class (here I added one button on this `UIview`). The `UIview` is loading and also an button is added on this `UIview`, but when I tapped on it, the button action is trowing exceptions. My code is below:

### Background class:

```
#import "MainView1.h"

@interface MainView1 ()

@end

@implementation MainView1

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

-(void)loadView1 :(UIView *)myview
{
    UIView * firstview =[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 50, 320, 430)];
    [firstview setBackgroundColor:[UIColor yellowColor]];

    UIButton *addProject = [UIButton buttonWithType: UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    addProject.frame = CGRectMake(100, 285, 100, 18);
    addProject.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    [addProject setTitle:@"Show View" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [addProject addTarget:self action:@selector(addProjectPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [firstview addSubview:addProject];

    [myview addSubview:firstview];
}

- (void)addProjectPressed:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"ok");

}
```

### Main Class:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "MainView1.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    MainView1 * m1 = [[MainView1 alloc]init];

    [m1 loadView1:self.view];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

I am loading that `UIView` from my Main class but button action is throwing an exception. What did I done wrong here?

Comment: What is the exception?

Answer (score 0):

You are calling a method from another class,so as soon as your view is finished loading it does not have access to the self which you added as the button target.

```
change your method like this
-(void)loadView1 :(UIView *)myview :(ViewController*)VC
{
    UIView * firstview =[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 50, 320, 430)];
    [firstview setBackgroundColor:[UIColor yellowColor]];
    UIButton *addProject=[[UIButton alloc]init];
    addProject = [UIButton buttonWithType: UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    addProject.frame = CGRectMake(100, 285, 100, 18);
    addProject.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    [addProject setTitle:@"Show View" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [addProject addTarget:VC action:@selector(ProjectPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [firstview addSubview:addProject];

    [myview addSubview:firstview];
}


and in main class
 call like this
[m1 loadView1:self.view :self];

also add you selector method to main class(ViewController.h)
- (void)ProjectPressed:(UIButton*)sender
{
    NSLog(@"ok");

}
```

Comment: thanks but in myview1 class if we not declare projectPrssed method there it's showing warning like unresolved selector(ProjectPressed) so is there any solution to remove that warning

Comment: hi,please add this to your ViewController.h file - (void)ProjectPressed:(UIButton*)sender;